# the command: import tensorflow_datasets as tfds yields an OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In windows 11 spyder(python 3.8)
The command:
`import tensorflow_datasets as tfds`

yeilds:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\gkhaz\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16868/45766485.py", line 1, in 
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

File "C:\Users\gkhaz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets_*init*_.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow_datasets import vision_language

File "C:\Users\gkhaz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\vision_language_*init*_.py", line 20, in 
from tensorflow_datasets.vision_language.wit import Wit

File "C:\Users\gkhaz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\vision_language\wit_*init*_.py", line 18, in 
from tensorflow_datasets.vision_language.wit.wit import Wit

File "C:\Users\gkhaz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\vision_language\wit\wit.py", line 25, in 
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Comment: This error you get only when your numbers are greater than `sys.maxsize`. Uninstall existing Tensorflow and install it again. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this issue resolved https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-datasets/ is now at 4.5.2 and should contain the [68fa6da](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/commit/68fa6da5a700f58c764c1cc9990e7a3938a1cae0) fix. Thank you!